# Bat replace comma(,) to new line and rename file

Tags: batch-file

I have a csv file with data in one line. I want the data after comma to be replaced to next line and  comma repalced to colon and rename csv to txt file.

File `text.csv`:

> ```
> Mn4pr,SS60S,P4NPR,F4NPR,K4NPR,T4NPR
> ```

Desired output:

> ```
> M4NPR; 
> SS60S;
> P4NPR;
> ```

I am not able to get the new line character working.

Batch script:

```
@ECHO OFF
 FOR %%I IN ("D:\path\to\files\text.csv") DO (
 SET "ext=%%~xI"
 SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
 set "line="
 for /F "delims=" %%a in (text.csv) do set "line=!line ;%%a"
 RENAME "%%I" "%%~nI!ext:~1!.csv"
 ENDLOCAL
                        )
```

Comment: Is PowerShell an option for this?

Comment: And what is your specific question? Do you want to skip certain entries? do you want to do case conversion? (looking at your sample input and output data)

Comment: @aschipfl "I want the data after comma to be replaced to next line and comma repalced to colon and rename csv to txt file." seems like it's one of those 3.

Comment: @aschipfl - It's pretty clear from the problem statement: ***I am not able to get the newline character working.*** - he's not successfully able to insert the newline to break the data across multiple lines.

Comment: not able to break the data across multiple lines, @aschipfl-  no i don't want skip any enteries nor want any conversion . just need to break the data into mutliple lines as Jeff said. Thanks jeff

Comment: is your csv a set amount of columns, or can it be any number of columns?

Comment: any number of columns

Comment: @JeffZeitlin, with my comment I primary wanted to point out that input and output data do not comply as described; in addition, there is no single sentence with a question mark typical for questions... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the input file does not contain quotation marks (`"`) and wild-cards (`*`, `?`), and assuming that all fields from the input CSV file are to be transferred to the output TXT file unedited, the following code could work for you:

```cmd
@echo off
> "text.txt" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("text.csv") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        for %%I in ("!LINE:,=" "!") do (
            endlocal
            echo(%%~I;
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
        endlocal
    )
)
REM del "text.csv"
```

The inner `for` loop splits the line at every `,`. The line-break is inserted implicitly by `echo`.

---

Here is an alternative approach not using `for /F` but input redirection `<` and `set /P` to read the single line of the CSV file:

```cmd
@echo off
< "text.csv" > "text.txt" (
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
    if defined LINE (
        for %%I in ("!LINE:,=" "!") do (
            endlocal
            echo(%%~I;
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        )
    )
    endlocal
)
REM del "text.csv"
```

By the way, to delete the original CSV file, remove `REM` in front of the `del` command line.